# The steps to calculate the derivative

Tags: matrix-calculus

$\frac{d}{d\mathbf{w}}Xsig(X^T\mathbf{w})=Xdiag(sig(X^T\mathbf{w})\odot (1-sig(X^Tw)))X^T$

I want to know the step of getting the above result, thank you.
The $sig$ is the element-wise sigmoid function. The convention is denominator layout.

Comment: Are $X$ and $w$ column vectors?

Comment: @PedroSebe $X$ has dimension $d\times n$ and $\mathbf w$ is $d \times 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of the logistic function, $\,s={\rm sig}(y),\,$ considered as an ordinary (scalar) function is
$$\frac{ds}{dy} = (s-s^2) \quad\implies\quad ds = (s-s^2)\,dy$$
Applying the function element-wise to a vector argument $\;(y=X^Tw)\;$
yields vector results
$$\eqalign{
s &= {\rm sig}(y) \\
ds &= (s-s\odot s)\odot dy \\
}$$
The elementwise/Hadamard products can be replaced by multiplication with a diagonal matrix, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
S &= {\rm Diag}(s) \\
ds &= (S-S^2)\,dy \\
}$$
Let's apply the above to the function in the question and calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= Xs \\
df &= X\,ds \\
   &= X(S-S^2)\,dy \\
   &= X(S-S^2)X^T\,dw \\
   &= XS(I-S)X^T\,dw \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}
   &= XS(I-S)X^T \\
}$$
So the gradient expression in the question is wrong.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the answer, could you explain why the middle term $S(I-S)\neq diag(sig(X^T\mathbf{w})\odot(1-sig(X^T\mathbf{w})))$ if I correct the bold symbol in my expression, I think that is a typo

Comment: @7337dtd You're right, $\,S(I-S)={\rm Diag}\Big(s\odot({\tt1}-s)\Big),\,$ it just looks awkward.

Comment: sure thank you.